# Добавление результата одного объекта в другой

Tags: javascript

Есть некий скрипт, который использует данные из объекта:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var val_data = {
      'uah': {
      'icon': "₴",
      'value': 1
    },
      'usd': {
      'icon': "$",
      'value': 26.50
    },
      'eur': {
      'icon': '€',
      'value': 28.43
    }
  };

...
```

Хотелось бы отойти от ручного прописывания соотношения валюты и брать данные отсюда:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5",true);
xhr.onload = function() {
  var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.write(result[2].ccy+"<br/>");
  document.write("курс продажи "+result[2].sale+"<br/>");
  document.write(result[0].ccy+"<br/>");
  document.write("курс продажи "+result[0].sale+"<br/>");
}
xhr.send();
```

Можно ли полученные данные из объекта с валютой поместить в существующий объект, чтобы не переделывать основной скрипт? Заменить `'value': 26.50` на что-то вроде этого: `'value': result[2].sale`? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно пробежаться циклом [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) по всем объектам массива `result` (каждый объект представляет описание валюты), и если такая валюта есть в `val_data`, то обновить соответствующее значение `value`.

```js
var val_data = {
    'uah': {
        'icon': '₴',
        'value': 1
    },
    'usd': {
        'icon': '$',
        'value': 26.50
    },
    'eur': {
        'icon': '€',
        'value': 28.43
    }
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var currency of result) {
        var currencyName = currency.ccy.toLowerCase();
        if (currencyName in val_data) {
            val_data[currencyName].value = currency.sale;
        }
    }
    console.log(val_data);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, отличное решение!